# How to create user page dynamically after registration of user

Tags: php, mediawiki

In mediawiki, how do I create a page for the user dynamically after user registration?

For example, after user `xyz` get registered, a user page is created with name `User:xyz`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a [MediaWiki extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extensions) that hooks into the [AddNewAccount](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AddNewAccount) hook.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368583/how-can-i-create-read-update-and-delete-mediawiki-articles-via-scripts) for the PHP code for creating new articles within an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely create a [bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBots) to do this, it probably wouldn't even be difficult.