# MediaWiki: Special "Create an account" behaviour

Tags: mediawiki

When a new user account is created in our MediaWiki system, the admin specifies the desired user login name and the real name. I'd like to automatically fill the user page and also create a special page according to these rules:

Provided the login of the new user is "LOGIN" and the real name is "FIRST SECOND",

1) a new page should be created named "SECFIR" (i.e. 3 letters of surname and 3 letters of first name), containing just "#REDIRECT:[[user:LOGIN]]", i.e. redirecting to the user page;

2) the user page should contain "{{getuser|SECFIR}}"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom hook function (event handler) using http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AddNewAccount - relatively straightforward PHP to do this
2. Same answer...

More at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514696

Comment: So do I understand correctly that I need to write an extension?

Comment: Yes. I thought one already existed for (2), but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I think you post answers my questions. I'll mark it accordingly as soon as I've tried it.